# cordova 3.0: Android: Connection is not defined

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

my first time experimenting with Apache Cordova 3.0.

downloaded lib, unziped cordova-android and cordova-js and created a project:

```
./create ~/Documents/andriod-projects/HelloWorld com.x.HelloWorld HelloWorld
- OK
```

res/xml/config.xml

```
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

on index.js device ready:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {

    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert("Network: "+states[networkState]);
}
```

when I emulate the project on my andriod I got in LogCat `Error:Connection is not defined`:

[image]

what I am missing? I have to attach a .js in order to Connection be declared?

Answer (score 12):

> Uncaught Refference error: Connection is not defined

is related to lack of a "Connection" object, which based on my experience with corodva 3.1.0 does not become available, even after a delay as benka suggested. This particular issue can be solved by using the constants of the navigator.connection object as below:

```
var states = {};
states[navigator.connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[navigator.connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[navigator.connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[navigator.connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[navigator.connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[navigator.connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[navigator.connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
states[navigator.connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
```

unfortunately in my case this was only the beginning of issues with network status on android as

```
navigator.connection.type
```

would always return 0 which is Unknown connection. Both on the android emulator and a device. A workaround which works for me is to call the plugin class directly:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    var conn = checkConnection();
    alert("Connection:"+conn);


}
function checkConnection(){
        var networkState;
        var test = cordova.exec(
                function(winParam) {networkState = winParam;},
                function(error) {alert("Network Manager error: "+error);},
                "NetworkStatus",
                "getConnectionInfo",
                []
        );
        return networkState;
}
```

this code has an ugly networkState assignment inside a function that could potentially be executed asynchronously after the checkConnection return statement, but as the native code returns PluginResult inside the execute function - this works. The networkState value returned does not match the navigator.connection. constants like:

```
navigator.connection.WIFI
```

You can see the values returned in the plugins source code here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/src/android/NetworkManager.java

Comment: They have SUCH frustratingly piss-poor documentation. This was the only way it worked for me, thanks very much mate!

Comment: Only way that works, yes you heard it right. But they will probably fix it. Thanks!

Comment: If there is no internet connection. Then what is the error message coming? i got "none"

Comment: Add `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>` in `<head>` tag

Answer (score 7):

I got the same issue with **Phonegap 3.0** on **Android 4.2.2 Api 17**.

Tried removing and reinstalling the Connection plugin trying both commands: Cordova or Phonegap local but didn't work.

What I have noticed in the logs is the following right after the ERROR message:

```js
10-11 14:31:40.360: E/Web Console(): Uncaught ReferenceError: Connection is not defined
10-11 14:31:40.380: D/CordovaNetworkManager(): Connection Type: wifi
```

So I was thinking that it actually looks like it was an **async callback** after successfully initializing Connection.type from **CordovaNetworkManager()** however it shouldn't be.

So I tried the following:

```js
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

setTimeout(function(){
    networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    alert('networkState = '+networkState);

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
 }, 500);
```

I know it looks a bit stupid but works every time.
What it does is first calls **navigator.connection.type** and then runs the whole function **500ms** later giving time to **CordovaNetworkManager** to initialize the **connection.type**.

Comment: thank you. after searching and searching, this is the ONLY solution that reliably gives me an accurate network status.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exact problem, but was able to fix it. Running the below commands as per the Phonegap Connection docs doesn't seem to work:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.network-information
```

Instead, I had to use:

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
```

Once I did that, it worked.

Comment: I don't have phonegap.

Comment: Does this basically mean the official plugin is broken? Seems a pretty fundamental problem that it's not registering the Connection constants object to the window.

Answer (score 5):

If you have included the plugin and are having the same problem it could be the order in which you included the plugin.

In order for the plugin to work I had to include the plugin after having added the platform.

```
$ cordova create

$ cordova platform add android 

$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolved by:

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using cordova 3.4.1 adding the plugin *org.apache.cordova.network-information* it fix my problem, try this:

**cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information**

I did not change any part of the code, as the help says:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md

Answer (score 0):

I am playing with the same thing and I think you need to install the features using [this page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface) by the use of cordova CLI.

Answer (score 0):

for me adding the plugin was not enough and didn't solve my issue...

Then I did in the CLI after I added the plugin

```
$ cordova build
```

and everything worked perfectly ! Make sure your /www file has the updated files because it will be used to erase the platforms/xxx/www files

Comment: Just warned you about it in my answer :/

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem, searching about this issue I found this question. I try many ideas, but the one did works was:
1- uninstall the network-information plugin
2- in the CMD -> cordova build
3- Install the plugin again
4- Build again.

After this The connection example works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Much in the same time at the end was that no load the js plugins that referenced. 
         cordova_plugins.js

it may happen that your project is not in the correct folder ... but in any case you can copy directly to a folder known for.

assets / www / plugins / org.apache.cordova.network-information

network.js "

Connection.js "

and loads in your html

Comment: The sentence structure here is making this nearly unintelligible. Can you please restructure?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I was calling checkConnection() inside $(function(){}).
It should be called by

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    checkConnection();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Now days in cordova 3.5 it seems

```
<access origin="*" />
```

is the correct CORS config.xml entry.

Note clarification on it being "ORIGIN" not "uri" and "subdomains" as it was before I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Cordova 3.5.0: `navigator.connection.type` returned `0` all the time and `navigator.onLine` was `true`. It was frustrating.

Then I found that the problem is only on my phone (with Android 2.3) and it works on emulator.

I guess that the problem can relate with Android version too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `PhoneGap 3.5.0:`navigator.connection.type`returned me`0`(unknown connection) and`navigator.onLine`(from HTML5) was`true` all the time.

The problem was **caused by the phone** (probably I have too old Android version on my phone) because it works with emulator and with tablet (where is Android 4.2) correctly :-(