# Phonegap Internet Connectivity State

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

My app needs to know whether the device has internet connectivity or not - if it does, the application will show data from a server, and if it doesn't, the app will display previously cached data.

How reliable is the `connection.type` variable in PhoneGap 3.1 (compiled with PhoneGap Build)? Also, if the `connection.type` is `UNKNOWN`, does that indicate that the device does or doesn't have internet?

Answer (score 1):

The connection variable is very reliable, just as any of the other Cordova API's, just make sure you aren't trying to call it until after the `deviceready` event has fired.

When the `connection.type` is `UNKNOWN`, that is most likely because the Connection Manager wasn't initialized yet; take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767933/cordova-3-0-andriod-connection-is-not-defined) to help with this issue.