# Connection is not defined in cordova network information plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have followed this article:

[to get network information of the device](http://www.joshmorony.com/monitoring-online-and-offline-states-in-an-ionic-application/) in ionic app for android.

It works fine on browser but when I install the compiled apk in android phone, it gives an error that says `Reference error : Connection is not defined.` at  line where I use `$cordovaNetwork.isOnline();`

I have been banging my head around and have done my due research and tried uninstalling and installing it in the order suggested but no help.

Help me fix this issue. This problem is probably not an issue with code and may be need some clever fix to get it working.

This same issue is being discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767933/cordova-3-0-android-connection-is-not-defined) but I have not really understood where is that given piece of code coming from.

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="starter" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--   <link href="lib/ionic/css/angular-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <!-- angular date picker css-->
    <link href="lib/datePicker/css/angular-pickadate.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/highcharts.js"></script>
     <script src="lib/ionic/js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>



    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
       <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>





  </head>
  <body ng-controller="LoginCtrl">

     <ion-nav-bar class="mob-bar-balanced">
     <!--  <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button> -->
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
app.factory('ConnectivityMonitor', ['$rootScope', '$cordovaNetwork', function($rootScope, $cordovaNetwork){
  return {
    isOnline: function(){
      if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){
       $rootScope.online = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
        return $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();    
      } else {
        $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
        return navigator.onLine;
      }
    },
    isOffline: function(){
      if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){
        $rootScope.online = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();   
        return !$cordovaNetwork.isOnline();    
      } else {
        $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
        return !navigator.onLine;
      }
    },
    startWatching: function(){
        if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){

          $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
            $rootScope.online =true;
            console.log("went online");
          });

          $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
             $rootScope.online =false;
            console.log("went offline");
          });

        }
        else {

          window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {
            $rootScope.online =true;
            console.log("went online");
          }, false);    

          window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
            $rootScope.online =false;
            console.log("went offline");
          }, false);  
        }       
    }
  }
}]);

.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('Login',{
    url:'/login',
    onEnter:["$state","$localStorage", '$rootScope' , '$ionicViewSwitcher',function($state,$localStorage, $rootScope, $ionicViewSwitcher){
        if((typeof($localStorage.userInfo)!== 'undefined') && (Object.keys($localStorage.userInfo).length !== 0)) {
                       $ionicViewSwitcher.nextTransition('none');
                       $state.go("Deployment");

        }
    }],
    templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
    controller:'LoginCtrl',
    resolve: {
            online: function(ConnectivityMonitor){
                return ConnectivityMonitor.isOnline();
        }
      }
  })
```

Comment: What command did you use to install network plugin? Can you give us here? Plus run `ionic plugin ls` and paste results here.

Comment: did you define your plugin in cordova-plugin.js and config.xml properly?

Comment: @SameerDonga these steps are not required by user. Ionic framework and cordova automaticaly update config.xm and cordova-plugin.js when plugin is installed.

Comment: I have tried both the command to install the plugin i.e cordova-plugin-network-information and org.apache.cordova.network-information @mudasserajaz

Comment: @SameerDonga: Indeed, I do not need to update the file , yet I am pretty sure it has been updated as while installing the app, It asks for these permissions.so That's not a problem

Comment: @SimranKaur Please put your index.html file in question.

Comment: @SimranKaur did you add permission in Manifest related to network?

Comment: No, I did not. It automatically gets added I suppose. I have not made any changes in manifest

Comment: and I have checked. It is there.

Comment: @SimranKaur the only thing left is to make sure that you have included `ng-cordova.js` before `cordova.js`.

Comment: I have. Definitely. Tried with min version as well. Getting same error with both

Comment: A lot of people on internet have complained about it . Is it a bug?

Comment: People were perhaps able to fix it with phonegap but I am not using it

Comment: It is not a bug, the posts you are refering are 1 or 2 years old.Plugin works fine. You are missing something small in your code may be. If you update your question with code like index.html and app.js then may be we can help.

Comment: @mudasserajaz: Could you please check the update?

Comment: yeah sure, checking.

Comment: You were right, There is something wrong with my code only. May be the way I am instantiating the factory from resolve? Because I tried to use variable in app.run function and they worked just fine. Would you please be able to state why it would not work if I instantiate the factory from resolve of controller and what would be the best place to instantiate the factory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87881/discussion-between-mudasser-ajaz-and-simran-kaur).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about the tutorial you're mentioning, however, you may want to check the post I wrote which goes literally step by step telling you where and why you should put some piece of code (may be useful if you're just starting with Ionic): http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/codeproject/check-network-information-change-with-ionic-famework/.

Also, I made the example code available freely on Github: https://github.com/Hitman666/IonicNetworkInfo. You can download the project (if you don't want to go through the steps yourself) build it for your device and test it on the device.

Here are the steps from the blog posts:

Start a new Ionic project by doing:

```
ionic start IonicNetworkInfo blank
```

Then, change the directory to the newly created IonicNetworkInfo:

```
cd IonicNetworkInfo
```

Install ngCordova with Bower:

```
bower install ngCordova
```

If by some chance you don’t have bower installed, you can install it with npm:

```
npm install bower -g
```

Open up the www/index.html file in your favorite editor, and add the reference to ngCordova (just above the cordova.js script):

```
<!-- This is what you should add, the cordova below you'll already have -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Install the ngCordova network plugin by executing the following command in your Terminal/Command prompt (you should do this from the root directory of your app; so, in our case the IonicNetworkInfo directory):

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

To check if you have successfully installed the plugin, you can run the following command (from the root directory – I won’t be repeating this anymore; when I say you should run some command from the Terminal/Command prompt that, in this case, means from the root directory of the application):

```
cordova plugin list
```

You should see the following output:

```
> cordova plugin list                                                                                                                           
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.15 "Network Information"
```

Open up the www/js/app.js file and add ngCordova to the dependencies list, so that basically the first line looks like this:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
```

Create a new controller in the www/js/app.js file called MyCtrl, with the following content:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaNetwork, $rootScope) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

        $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
        $scope.isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
        $scope.$apply();

        // listen for Online event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
            $scope.isOnline = true;
            $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

            $scope.$apply();
        })

        // listen for Offline event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
            console.log("got offline");
            $scope.isOnline = false;
            $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

            $scope.$apply();
        })

  }, false);
})
```

In this controller you attach an event listener on the deviceready event (because it could be that the device would not have been yet initialized when this code runs) and you get the network information with:

```
$cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
```

The information, about weather you’re connected to the internet is obtained with the following line:

```
$scope.isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
```

Then, you register two events $cordovaNetwork:online and $cordovaNetwork:online which trigger when the device gets online/offline. In them you then just update the $scope variables ().
Just for reference, the whole content of the www/js/app.js file should be:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaNetwork, $rootScope) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

  });
})

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaNetwork, $rootScope) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

        $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
        $scope.isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
        $scope.$apply();

        // listen for Online event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
            $scope.isOnline = true;
            $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

            $scope.$apply();
        })

        // listen for Offline event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
            console.log("got offline");
            $scope.isOnline = false;
            $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

            $scope.$apply();
        })

  }, false);
});
```

In the index.html file, inside the ion-content tag paste the following content:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <h1>Network: {{network}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="card">
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <ion-toggle ng-model="isOnline" ng-checked="item.checked">
            <h1 ng-show="isOnline">I'm online</h1>
            <h1 ng-show="! isOnline">I'm offline</h1>
        </ion-toggle>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically what we do here is we show the contents of the network variable (which is attached to the $scope via the controller). Also, by using the ion-toggle component we show the “I’m online” / “I’m offline” notifications.

Just for reference, the content of the whole index.html file should look like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>

        <ion-content padding="true">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                    <h1>Network: {{network}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                    <ion-toggle ng-model="isOnline" ng-checked="item.checked">
                        <h1 ng-show="isOnline">I'm online</h1>
                        <h1 ng-show="! isOnline">I'm offline</h1>
                    </ion-toggle>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

In order to test this application you should run it on your device (because you can’t disable network in iOS simulator). If you have an Android device plugged to your computer (and all the SDKs in place) you can run the following to commands to get your application running on your Android device:

```
ionic build android && ionic run android
```

Comment: Excellent answer @Nikola, one update, it should be "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information" now as things have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have not installed Network-Plugin. Please check this.

Comment: Try to provide some link

Comment: And if you don't know how to format link then just put the whole link in answer. I'll format it for you;)

Answer (score 0):

Now, I think it would be a better approach to use

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function()  {
     $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
     $scope.isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();

     $scope.$apply();
});
```

instead of document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {